# Using 'out' in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, nxopen

I am working with a `List` of `Component` objects, `componentList`.

`Component` has method `GetPosition` which returns position of a component via `component.GetPosition(out position, out orientation)`.
I can get X, Y, Z via `position.X, position.Y, position.Z`.

I have a separate `List<CSVPart>` imported from a CSV file. Each list item also has X, Y, Z. I want to find `Component` which matches X, Y, Z from the list of CSV parts.

I have tried:

```
foreach (CSVPart p in csvParts)
{
    foundComponent = componentList
        .Where(c => c.Name == p.PartNumber & ... == p.X & ... == p.Y & ... == p.Z
        )
}
```

Where Name corresponds to PartNumber and ... corresponds to me staring blankly at the screen.
I've tried nesting the subsequent statements to compare X, Y, Z in {} but nothing I've tried worked. How do I get the `out` results into this Linq query? Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you don't try to do it in a single expression. Instead, either write a method that does the matching you want and refer to that in your query, or use a block-bodied lambda:

```cs
foreach (CSVPart p in csvParts)
{
    var foundComponent = componentList.FirstOrDefault(c =>
    {
        // Avoid finding the position if the name doesn't match.
        if (c.Name != p.PartNumber)
        {
            return false;
        }
        c.GetPosition(out var position, out var _);
        return position.X == p.X && position.Y == p.Y && position.Z == p.Z;
    });
    // foundComponent will be null or the first match
}
```

(I've changed from `Where` to `FirstOrDefault` as the name suggests you're trying to find a single value...)